# Print current month Calendar

Tags: c

I'm working on a program for more than 3 months now and at some point today i decided that the program at some point should print the current given calendar.

The calendar should look like this:

> ```
> Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa
>         1   2   3   4   5
> 6   7   8   9   10  11  12
> 13  14  15  16  17  18  19
> 20  21  22  23  24  25  26
> 27  28  29  30
> ```

So I created the following function:

```
void printWeek(int firstDay,int lastDay){
int i;

printf("Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa\n");
for(i = 1; i <= lastDay; i++) {
    printf("%2d  ", i);
    if((i + firstDay - 1)%7 ==0){
        printf("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

and prints the following:

```
 Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7
 8   9  10  11  12  13  14
15  16  17  18  19  20  21
22  23  24  25  26  27  28
29  30
```

The month which we are speaking is September (2015) and should look like this:

> ```
> Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa
>          1   2   3   4   5 
>  6  7   8   9  10  11  12
> 13  14  15  16  17  18  19
> 20  21  22  23  24  25  26
> 27  28  29  30
> ```

because September 2015 start Tuesday not Sunday,  I created another function which returns the day number (`Sunday == 0`, `Monday == 1`...`Saturday == 6`):

```
int dayWeek(int d, int m, int y){
int month[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
int day[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int i;

    if (y % 4 == 0 && (y % 100 != 0 || y % 400 == 0)){
        month[1] = 29;
    }

    if (y < 1900 || m < 1 || m > 12 || d < 1 || d > month[m - 1]) {
        printf("This is an invalid date.\n");
        exit(1);
    }



    for (i = 1900; i < y; i++){
        if (i % 4 == 0 && (i % 100 != 0 || i % 400 == 0)){
            d += 366;
        }else{
            d += 365;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m - 1; i++){
        d += month[i];
    }

    return day[d % 7];
}
```

At some point the program prints the calendar from first day  and the last day of given data.

Question is: how can i have the following output:

> ```
> Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa
>          1   2   3   4   5
> 6   7   8   9   10  11  12
> 13  14  15  16  17  18  19
> 20  21  22  23  24  25  26
> 27  28  29  30
> ```

I already know that the function `dayWeek()` returns 2 which is Tuesday (the first week day from September 2015) but I do not know how to change the function `printWeek()`; to print September 1 as Tuesday and not Sunday. Hope you understand my poor English.

Here is the code which I have now:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int dayWeek(int d, int m, int y){
    int month[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    int day[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int i;

    if (y % 4 == 0 && (y % 100 != 0 || y % 400 == 0)){
        month[1] = 29;
    }

    if (y < 1900 || m < 1 || m > 12 || d < 1 || d > month[m - 1]) {
        printf("This is an invalid date.\n");
        exit(1);
    }



    for (i = 1900; i < y; i++){
        if (i % 4 == 0 && (i % 100 != 0 || i % 400 == 0)){
            d += 366;
        }else{
            d += 365;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m - 1; i++){
        d += month[i];
    }

    return day[d % 7];
}

void printWeek(int firstDay,int lastDay){
    int i;

    printf("Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa\n");
    for(i = 1; i <= lastDay; i++) {
        printf("%2d  ", i);
        if((i + firstDay - 1)%7 ==0){
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(void){
    int day = 1;
    int month = 9;
    int year = 2015;

    int weekDay = dayWeek(day,month,year);
    printf("The day of the Week is\t%d\n\n",weekDay);

    printWeek(day,30);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: comment above your functions and loops to indicate their purpose in the existent code, this will point out any possible corrections. In addition to that skip any empty lines to make your code more concise and easy to read (without too much scrolling).

Comment: @simplicisveritatis, Sir this is a fast code, the orogonal code looks different, i tried to show a minimal code that will compile to make you understand what i need.

Comment: no worries, it was just a suggestion to help the reader. I don't doubt that the original code looks better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know the day of the first of the month – 2, for this month – and so all you need to do is print the correct number of spaces before you output the first day number in the `printWeek` function:

```
for (i=0; i<weekday; i++)
    printf ("--  ");
```

(I used dashes for clarity). That will offset the first day of the week correctly:

```
Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa
--  --   1   2   3   4   5   6   7  
 8   9  10  11  12  13  14  
15  16  17  18  19  20  21  
22  23  24  25  26  27  28  
29  30
```

but since you test on the day index, the first line will stick out and next lines will not be correct. So adjust your line adjustment by adding that weekday again:

```c
if((i + firstDay + weekday - 1)%7 ==0)
```

The full routine, including passing on a first-day-of-the-week variable, then becomes

```
void printWeek (int weekday, int firstDay,int lastDay){
    int i;

    printf("Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa\n");
    for (i=0; i<weekday; i++)
        printf ("--  ");
    for(i = 1; i <= lastDay; i++) {
        printf("%2d  ", i);
        if((i + firstDay + weekday - 1)%7 ==0){
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

and outputs as expected:

```
The day of the Week is  2

Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa
--  --   1   2   3   4   5  
 6   7   8   9  10  11  12  
13  14  15  16  17  18  19  
20  21  22  23  24  25  26  
27  28  29  30
```

Answer (score 2):

So this is a common problem, where the data is not quite aligned.

You need a counter for "day of week", and a separate counter for the date in the month.

I have renamed `printWeek` to `printMonth`.  Send in the initial day of the week (`firstWeekDay`)  (0 - 6).  Then after printing the heading, create spaces for the initial date location.

Finally the week end is based on `i` and the `firstWeekDay` so when to add the new line is modified.

```
void printMonth(int firstDay,int lastDay, int firstWeekDay ){
    int i;
    printf("Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa\n");
    for(i = 0; i < firstWeekDay ; i ++ ) {
        printf("    ");
    }
    for(i = 1; i <= lastDay; i++) {
        printf("%2d  ", i);
        if((i + firstDay + firstWeekDay - 1)%7 ==0){
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(void){
    int day = 1;
    int month = 9;
    int year = 2015;

    int weekDay = dayWeek(day,month,year);
    printf("The day of the Week is\t%d\n\n",weekDay);

    printMonth(day,30, weekDay);
    return 0;
}
```